# Display a subset of Events already fetched in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

The [documents](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) are great when you know what you are doing. I was unable to find any google fodder that I could use for a problem I barely know how to explain, so here it goes.

Using Fullcalendar 2.2.6 (latest version at time of writing) I can display all the events for the calendar using the following config.

```
full_calendar_options = 
{"editable":true,
"header":{"left":"prev,next, today", "center":"title","right":"month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"},
"defaultView":"agendaWeek",
"height":500,
"slotMinutes":15,
"dragOpacity":0.5,
"selectable":true,
"timeFormat":"h:mm t{ - h:mm t}",
"businessHours":true,
"events":"/events/get_events"}
```

Now, I get some JSON like this:

```
[{"id":3,"title":"Jim Jumper","description":"Lifting Room","start":"2015-01-15T13:00:00Z","end":"2015-01-15T13:30:00Z","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"backgroundColor":"#12ab12","textColor":"#32ac32"},
{"id":4,"title":"Jim Jumper","description":"Lifting Room","start":"2015-01-16T13:30:00Z","end":"2015-01-16T13:00:00Z","allDay":true,"recurring":false,"backgroundColor":"#12ab12","textColor":"#32ac32"},
{"id":6,"title":"Joan Lifter","description":"No Room Booked","start":"2015-01-17T08:00:00Z","end":"2015-01-17T08:30:00Z","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"backgroundColor":"#efab12","textColor":"#323232"},
{"id":7,"title":"Joan Lifter","description":"No Room Booked","start":"2015-01-17T04:00:00Z","end":"2015-01-17T04:30:00Z","allDay":false,"recurring":false,"backgroundColor":"#efab12","textColor":"#323232"}
]
```

QUESTION:
What is the best strategy to **sort by User** after you render a view? To me, i get why we are doing an ajax call, but since we have the data already, it'd be awesome to just sort, and display, a subset of the data we already have.

Currently, I do the following in JS.

```
$('#trainer_select').on('change', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var view = $('.calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
      $.ajax({
       type: 'get',
       dataType: 'script',
       async: true,
       url: "http://localhost:3000/events/get_events",
       data: {
     start: view.intervalStart.format(),
     end: view.intervalEnd.format(),
     user: $(this).val()
       },
        success: $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvents')
      });
   });
```

I'm basically calling the same url, just passing a `user` parameter. However, since there is `start`, `end` params magic in full calendar, you kind of have to reverse engineer how it's called.  That's why the data array in the JSON  uses the view.  That was tricky enough to figure out, as a side note... so you are welcome :-).

I see the AJAX call being made successfully, printing out the results shows there is only 2 records.  I am stuck at the point where i then have to render this new data into the view. Since renderEvents doesn't take any arguments, on success it just reRenders the events url in the initial code.

Strategy and Moar Questions:

1. How do i get this code to reRender the data, on success, from the new Get request i made?
2. If this isn't the right way, what is?
3. I hear some people add `EventSources` but will full calendar know to use that new `EventSource` in the rerendered view then?
4. Lastly, I'm thinking that maybe I should just hack `get_events` url on my server to take a blank `user` param, as default, and update the original `full_calendar_options` *(somehow)* to accept `data: {user: ""}` or something... maybe that saves all these headaches, but doesn't help answer these questions though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure I entirely understand the question(s) but I'll attempt something.

### Event Sources

You almost always want to use these. If you are loading data from a server, you usually use a json feed (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/).

How they work:

- You specify a script on your server
- The fullcalendar queries it whenever it needs data. This happens:

  - On some view changes
  - When the `next`, `prev` or `today` buttons are pressed
- When it queries the server it sends the date range it wants data for. So the request URL might look like: `/myfeed.php?start=2013-12-01&end=2014-01-12`

The simplest form of this looks like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/myfeed.php'
});
```

But you need to attach data to it. Furthermore, you need to attach data that changes based on your current `#trainer_select`. This is done with the dynamic data parameter.

### Dynamic data parameter

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: '/myfeed.php',
        data: function() { // returns the data object that will be sent with each ajax request
            return {
                user: $('#trainer_select').val();
            };
        }
    }
});
```

And then, when the `#trainer_select` changes, call `refetchEvents`.

```
$('#trainer_select').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
}
```

### Alternative

The above is the "right" way to do it. Or the author's intended way, anyway. But you mention that if you already have the data, *why can't you just filter the stuff you want to display* (I think that's what you meant).

So, here's one way to do that.

### Conditionally hide events when they render

You can get the data with a script as per the very top code block. I still recommend only getting the data within a timeframe since this will scale much better. Remember, that top code block sends `/myfeed.php?start=2013-12-01&end=2014-01-12`. You just have to handle the dates server side.

Once you've set a source for the events, make use of the [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) callback option.

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    // The server should have returned events with a .user property
    if (event.user != $('#trainer_select').val()) {
        $(element).addClass("hideme"); // This class should have "display: none"
    }
}
```

And then set a listener on the `#trainer_select` and call [`rerenderEvents`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/)

```
$('#trainer_select').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar("rerenderEvents"); //this shouldn't trigger an ajax call
}
```

Here is a working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/5d6jonu8/5/). But it's with static events rather than json feed ones.